# Run simultaneously UWSGI and ASGI with Django

Tags: django, uwsgi, django-channels, daphne

I'm currently  running a Django (2.0.2) server with [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) having 10 workers

I'm trying to implement a real time chat and I took a look at [Channel](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). 
The documentation mentions that the server needs to be run with [Daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne), and Daphne needs an asynchronous version of UWSGI named [ASGI](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asgi.html).

I manged to install and setup ASGI and then run the server with daphne but with only one worker (a limitation of ASGI as I understood) but the load it too high for the worker.

Is it possible to run the server with uWSGI with 10 workers to reply to HTTP/HTTPS requests and use ASGI/Daphne for WS/WSS (WebSocket) requests ?
Or maybe it's possible to run multiples instances of ASGI ?

Comment: If you use a load balancer/proxy server like nginx you can route requests depending on their URL or Upgrade headers to uWSGI or Daphne, yes. See http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/deploying.html#running-asgi-alongside-wsgi

Comment: The documentations talks about `Running ASGI alongside WSGI` (what I want) but there is not example code about how it's possible to implement this `load-balancer` with `Upgrade: WebSocket`. Is it possible to have more precision and some example ?

Comment: @yofee Can you look at to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58778048/8353711)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is possible to run WSGI alongside ASGI here is an example of a Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80; 

    server_name {{ server_name }};
    charset utf-8;


    location /static {
        alias {{ static_root }};
    }

    # this is the endpoint of the channels routing
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8089; # daphne (ASGI) listening on port 8089
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8088; # gunicorn (WSGI) listening on port 8088
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        client_max_body_size 50m;
    }
}
```

To use the `/ws/` correctly, you will need to enter your URL like that:

```
ws://localhost/ws/your_path
```

Then nginx will be able to upgrade the connection.

Comment: are sessions shared in this setup?

Comment: Yes, they are shared.

Comment: Are you sure ? This seems to me like you will end up running two instances of your application. One by Daphne and one by gunicorn.

Comment: Sessions are usually stored in the database or some other shared location

Comment: Can we implement this Apache?