# 502 Bad Gateway Nginx error while deploying Django Channels app using Daphne on Google App Engine (Flexible)

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform, django-channels, daphne

My Django app was working fine on Google App Engine (Flexible) using gunicorn as entrypoint in the app.yaml file. I needed to add websockets to it so I used Django Channels (with redis). This works beautifully on my local machine (Windows 10).

For deployment, I changed my entrypoint to daphne on port 8080 since that's the default on GAE (using $PORT produces the same effect), so my yaml file now looks like this:

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

entrypoint: daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8080 my_project_name.asgi:application
```

I've checked my .asgi file and requirements.txt to ensure everything is ok and the packages are the latest versions.

But after deploying it, I get a `"502 Bad Gateway Nginx"` error.

The Stackdriver logs (nginx.error) on the GCP cloud console say the below:

```
[error] 33#33: *341 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting 
to upstream, client: 172.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "172.17.0.1:8080", host: "my_project_name.appspot.com"
```

I don't recognize those IPs for upstream server or client, and I don't know what to do next. I've tried numerous things over the last 4 days, including:

1. using various different ports (8000, 8001 etc)
2. adding an nginx.conf file (based on [this documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html)) in my project directory, which seems to make no difference
3. Adding a line in the runtime_config section of the yaml file that says "nginx_conf_http_include: nginx.conf"

4.Using Unix sockets to start the daphne server in the entrypoint like "entrypoint: daphne -u /tmp/daphne.sock my_project_name.asgi:application

5. Deleting the entrypoint altogether after declaring the daphne server in the nginx.conf file

None of this helps. The logs stay the same, the error stays the same. I've read SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46175452/django-channels-nginx-production) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794936/run-simultaneously-uwsgi-and-asgi-with-django) but I don't know how to apply them to GAE Flex since I'm not directly operating the VM instance. Please help.

Comment: `daphne -b 127.0.0.1` might be limiting to local connections only have you tired `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have tried 0.0.0.0. Same error.

Comment: I encounter the exact same problem. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Stephan_Berlin I moved to Heroku and it was smooth. Sorry for the late reply.